# Getting a pointer to function in llvm

Tags: llvm

I'm trying to get a pointer to a function that returns a void and has a string as arguement. The code compiles successfully, but when running the pass, it fails with the following error:

**Assertion `(i >= FTy->getNumParams() || FTy->getParamType(i) == Args[i]->getType()) && "Calling a function with a bad signature!"' failed.**

Can someone please help. How do I create the signature for such a function correctly?

```
        StructType *StructTy_class_std__basic_string = mod->getTypeByName("class.std::basic_string");
         if (!StructTy_class_std__basic_string) 
         {
             StructTy_class_std__basic_string = StructType::create(mod->getContext(), "class.std::basic_string");
        }
         LLVMContext &Context = mod->getContext();
         Constant *c = mod->getOrInsertFunction("_Z5countSs",
                  Type::getVoidTy(Context),
                  StructTy_class_std__basic_string, NULL);
         Function *funtPtr = cast<Function>(c);
```

And this is how I make a call to CreateCall:

```
            Constant *a = ConstantDataArray::getString(mod->getContext(), instruction->getOpcodeName(), true);
            builder.SetInsertPoint(instruction);
            builder.CreateCall(count,a);
```

Comment: Can you show the call instruction you're making?

Comment: I realized that that's what I'm doing wrong. Could you please suggest what should be they call function? Let's assume I have to call this function with string contained in a variable (const char *a = "hello"). What should my CreateCall look like in this case?

Comment: I updated my code. Can you please check now. Thanks.